# Hide directly viewing content for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm using a lot of custom post types for creating sidebars, footers, etc and would like to hide direct viewing of these post types. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) allows you to specify whether a post is 'publicly_queryable'

> publicly_queryable
>   (boolean) (optional) Whether queries can be performed on the front end as part of parse_request().
>
> Default: value of public argument
>   Note: The queries affected include the following (also initiated when rewrites are handled)
>
> - ?post_type={post_type_key}
> - ?{post_type_key}={single_post_slug}
> - ?{post_type_query_var}={single_post_slug}

It doesn't mention anything about queries of the form `?p=`, and from memory, these will still serve your custom post types event with the publicly_queryable set to false. To prevent this you can hook onto `template_redirect` and redirect to a different (404?) page.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I also tested it with ?p= query and it still delivers a 404 which is what I want.